# Facebook and Pinterest shares not working in mobile site

Tags: facebook, mobile, share

I have an FB page tab store and currently we are trying to build a mobile optimized site using the same set of code.
m.siteurl is the mobile site URL (both web and mobile shares the same set of code). Everything works fine except Facebook and Pinterest share.
I was able to share in FB two to three time, but most of the time nothing happens. Pinterest didn't work for me in mobile.
As mentioned above m.siteurl is my mobile site URL and if I take the same in desktop every thing works fine, only with the mobile browser I have issue.

We are using FB.ui javascript method with parameters method,link,picture,name,description. Is there any additional parameters or method  to take care this.

Please can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide some code if you would like some help

Answer (score 0):

Even i am stuck with it. The fact Jscript-sdk uses popups for its actions. So share button Fb.Login() methods wont work in mobile. I myself had to change my website with a manual fb login instead of js-sdk.